# Reading Json from Gson result in error

Tags: java, android, gson, json

I am trying to parse a simple Json String using Gson.

```
String json = "{'FoodMenuRS':{'Status':'Success','TotalResults':4}}";
```

For reading json i am writing the code:

```
Info info = gson.fromJson(json, Info.class);
```

and here Info is

```
public class Info {
@SerializedName("FoodMenuRS")
public String FoodMenuRS;

@SerializedName("Status")
public String Status;

@SerializedName("TotalResults")
public String TotalResults;

public String getFoodMenuRS() {
    return FoodMenuRS;
}

public void setFoodMenuRS(String foodMenuRS) {
    FoodMenuRS = foodMenuRS;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}

public String getTotalResults() {
    return TotalResults;
}

public void setTotalResults(String totalResults) {
    TotalResults = totalResults;
}
}
```

But while parsing exception ocuurs:

```
The JsonDeserializer StringTypeAdapter failed to deserialize json object {"Status":"Success","TotalResults":4}
```

And if i remove 'FoodMenuRs' it runs correctly. Please help.

Comment: What if you make the value of TotalResults wrapped in quotes?  You have it defined as a String not an Int.

Comment: Also tried with taking as int, result is same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with the Gson library but from what i see and the error your receiving it would seem like it's a hierarchy issue.

Your `Info` class **hasA** `FoodMenuRS`, `Status`, and `TotalResults` but your json tells a different story.  It would seem your json is looking for an object called 'FoodMenuRS' that has two fields called `Status` and `TotalResults`.  My logic seems to be confirmed by that fact that it works when you remove the `FoodMenuRS`.  Does this help?

Comment: removing "FoodMenuRs" run the code without exception but do not show values of Status and TotalResult. It shows Status = null and TotalResult=0.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code I am able to get the answer.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String json = "{'FoodMenuRS':'ABC','Status':'Success','TotalResults':4}";
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Info info = gson.fromJson(json, Info.class); 
            System.out.println(info.toString());

        }


public class Info { 
    @SerializedName("FoodMenuRS") 
    public String FoodMenuRS;  
    @SerializedName("Status") 
    public String Status;  
    @SerializedName("TotalResults") 
    **public int TotalResults;**
    /**
     * @return the foodMenuRS
     */
    public String getFoodMenuRS() {
        return FoodMenuRS;
    }
    /**
     * @param foodMenuRS the foodMenuRS to set
     */
    public void setFoodMenuRS(String foodMenuRS) {
        FoodMenuRS = foodMenuRS;
    }
    /**
     * @return the status
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    /**
     * @param status the status to set
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }
    /**
     * @return the totalResults
     */
    public int getTotalResults() {
        return TotalResults;
    }
    /**
     * @param totalResults the totalResults to set
     */
    public void setTotalResults(int totalResults) {
        TotalResults = totalResults;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info [FoodMenuRS=" + this.FoodMenuRS + ", Status=" + this.Status
                + ", TotalResults=" + this.TotalResults + "]";
    }
}
```

you can use int or String for TotalResults it will give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

That's propably occur when you set @RequestBody wrong in controller that receive data from client. You see when JSON adapter doesnt know the request.

Hope that'll

Regards :)